# Null safetly check kotlin formating

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm fairly new to Kotlin and I am not familiar with the best practice for scoping functions or null checks. How do i rewrite this null check in a clearer way?

```
return item.feed != null 
    && item.feed.subject != null 
    && item.feed.subject == subject.trim())
```

Comment: `item?.feed?.subject == subject.trim()`. `?.` operator gives `null` if variable is null.

Comment: if either feed or item are null will this line return false?

Comment: Exactly, unless for some reason `subject.trim()` returns `null`, in which case the condition will become `null == null` which is true. But if `subject` is a String then there is no reason for this to happen.

Comment: Thank you! that was the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also see this diagram:

[image]

source: typealias.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have declared your attribute as nullable, you can use the `?` operator to check if it is null before calling a method, like this:

```
subject?.trim()
```